# how to prevent every time textbox sets datetime.now.date value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a text box that sets current datetime value for showing up current date record on first page load. This sets first time correctly but every time it  just sets up current date when page load occurs. Here is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Fill_Combo();
            Get_Data();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_date_from.Text.Trim()))
            {
                CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
                txt_date_from.Text = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when any button clicks first then it's set Current Date. How do i prevent it when textbox have already a value selected by user side.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: i have one text box which sets default value as current datetime. it's fine first load. when user select other date from calender extender this date not set on every post back. Every page loads it's set current datetime value which already have value previous time.

Comment: When you change the date it does not trigger a postback. Find an event to trigger when you do the date change. On that event assign the new value to the text box. Then it will reflect on all the other postbacks.

Comment: can u please explain with some code example

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't give you a sample. But check this link https://forums.asp.net/t/1610663.aspx?CalendarExtender+DateChange+event+on+the+server+side